# Unable to find the socket transport "udp"

Tags: php, sockets, udp

When i use the script "GoldSource Server Info" on the ip of cs 1.6 i receive this error but only on web host, on localhost all work correctly, why? (sorry for my english)

> not connected

View Line 92.

Code:

```
https://pastebin.com/D1kY6byv
```

Or i tried this code:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("udp://188.213.212.121", 27015, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    echo fread($fp, 26);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

And i receive this error

> Unable to find the socket transport "udp" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?

Comment: soooo ... did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP ?

Comment: Well, how to enable socket transport "udp"?